# Shortest Levenshtein Distance? Do I need it?

Tags: java, android, string, levenshtein-distance

I want to look up a `String` in a `String[]` for the best match of the query. I have heard of Levenshtein Distance. But I cannot determine if I need it or not.

Suppose, I have a `String query = "Examples"` and

```
String[] arrayStr = new String[] {"The Examples String", "The Example String", "Example", "Examples String", "Example String", "Examplestring"};
```

Now, I want to get the `Example` from the `String[]` as the best match.

So, Do I need Levenshtein Distance to do it?

Alternatively, If someone can point me a fast implementation of Levenshtein Distance for Java, it would be great. I would like to check if it works with all the kind of strings that I have. (Basically I have around 10k strings to match from 10k arrays.)

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java

Comment: Levenstein distance is simply the amount of charactes you have to add/remove/change to transform one sting into another. it doesn't really tell something about the quality of the match. eg. "example" -> "examples of very popular sting operations" -> distance 34 and "example" -> "expected ampersand lesson" -> distance 18. I doubt that the shortest levenstein distance will always give you the best match

Comment: @MarcoForberg You are wrong, because it does.

Comment: Okay if you say so i guess you are right. never tried this algorithm in that way. @Writwick: If you don't want to implement it on your own you can as well use the implementation in Apache commons' `StringUtils`: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Levenshtein Distance is the goto algorithm for this.
You can find implementations in many languages, including Java, at
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: As @marco-forberg pointed out, Apache's StringUtils has an implementaion - docs at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

as well as an implementation of the 'Jaro Winkler Distance' algorithm, 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getJaroWinklerDistance(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: You can find one more example mention here.. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/FindtheLevenshteindistancebetweentwoStrings.htm