# Computing the shortest path between two words?

Tags: java

I need to calculate the distance of two words that are found in a list. And by distance I mean the number of words that are found in between the source and target word.
ex. dog -> cog -> cot -> cat
Therefore the path distance would be three, as the edit distance between each word in the path is one. But I don't know how to deal with words with edit distances greater then one.

Comment: And do you also have a question? One that fits the requirements of SO?

Comment: Stack overflow is not meant to supply you with free code meeting your requirements. Make some effort, and come ask specific questions to issues you face if any arise

Comment: I would look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274183/shortest-levenshtein-distance-do-i-need-it

Comment: Is it a requirement that all intermediate words can be found in the dictionary? Which dictionary?

Comment: Yes. And the dictionary is just some text file with a single word on each line.

Comment: One way to think of it is as a maze (labyrinth). A cell is a word and a path between cells is when two words differ only by one letter. Search for a maze solving algorithm, it should be described in many places.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
    List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    Boolean done=false;
    Boolean found=false;
    int dist=0;
    string begin="dog";
    string end="cat";

    // add 4 different values to list
    animals.add("dog");
    animals.add("cog");
    animals.add("cot");
    animals.add("cat");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < animals.size()&&!done) {
        if(animals.get(i).equals(begin)) found=true;
        if(found){
            dist++;
            if(animals.get(i).equals(end))done=true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(dist);
```